# Nginx cannot forward request

Tags: nginx

I have a local server. I want to forward requests to it through an nginx server.

The local url is: `http://192.168.0.1/icon.jpg`. I tried some of settings but I dont know why just option 1 is working

**Option 1:**

```
location ~ "/fw/(?<img>[a-z]+)$" {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1/$img.jpg;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```

=> The url now: http://domain/fw/icon

**Option 2:**

```
location ~ "/fw/(?<img>[a-z]+)\.jpg$" {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1/$img.jpg;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```

=> The url now: http://domain/fw/icon.jpg

**Option 3:**

```
location ~ "/fw/(?<img>.+)$" {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1/$img;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```

=> The url now: http://domain/fw/icon.jpg

Comment: Do you have any other `location` blocks in your configuration. Particularly, another `location` that matches URIs ending with `.jpg`?

Comment: Yes I have another location in my configuration. I commented out that block but still the same